# Where is the link back?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-norepro, stackexchange

Where is the link back to ubuntu.stackexchange.com from meta.ubuntu.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Lol... just found it. It's tiny... but now that I know where it is, it makes perfect sense. It's on the top bar, right from log out, left of about.

Comment: You should answer your own question now that you've found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer looks out-of-date now. Here is an updated screenshot I took; the link you want is now called **main**:

[image: links screenshot]

Comment: Wait...how my answer become the new accepted answer? Nice surprise, nonetheless.

Answer (score 5):

It's called `parent`. Left of `faq` in the navigation bar right at the top.

It's not always right of the `log out` link. Get 2000 reputation and it's right of a `tools` link:

[image: Look ma! Tools menu!]